# Private way to connect to my SQL Server database

Tags: linux, python, sql-server

I'm running on linux and I am using a SQL Server database server on some other machine.

My python code has to sit in a directory that many other users have read access to.

I also have a "GenericTaskRunner" linux user And "GenericTaskRunner" databaseuser.

How do I connect to the SQL Server database using the "GenericTaskRunner" linux and SQL Server user without leaking "GenericTaskRunner"'s database credentials?

Comment: If your credentials are hardcoded then you'll need to prevent users from being able to read them (obviously), or they'll be able to steal them.

Comment: Does the python code start automatically, or can you interactively start it and input the credentials?

Comment: That protects the transportation. the issue is that my code somehow needs to get and use the credentials for the database user. I can't just store the user and pass in the script because other users will be able to read the code.

Comment: I want it to run automatically. it will run as a specific user on linux to authenticate to a specific user on SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You could create [stored procedures](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure) that ONLY do what your script needs to do and then [limit GenericTaskRunner's permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure) on the database to allow it to execute those stored procedures ONLY. This way, even if the rest of users have the database credentials, they can only do what the script can do.

If this was not enough, then you should consider executing your Python script on a server instead of giving all users access to it.

**Edit:** I see in the comments that you plan to execute the Python script automatically as a Linux user. Another option is to store the database credentials in a file which only that user has read access to, and read it from the Python script when connecting to the database.

Answer (score 1):

To connect from Linux to SQL Server you pretty much have to have a password (unless this has changed recently).

I would put the password in a file, configure the ownership and permissions so that only the authorised user can access it, and have the script read the password from the file.

If this was Windows you could use Integrated Windows Authentication, have the script run as a domain user that has the appropriate privileges on SQL Server. Kind of doing the same thing under the hood, but seems cleaner somehow.